# Trouble filtering array with conditions

Tags: jquery, arrays, each

I am trying to filter an array for different sets of swatches using a class as a key for each set so the js knows what to pull from variables with stored swatch positions. At the moment though if I log, for example set1, it returns the last position only. Also the hasClass method isn't finding the set classes. All in all I think I'm on the right path logically but I'm jumbling a few things up perhaps in terms of approach and efficiency. I tried searching around for solutions on this for a little while to no avail so here I am. I appreciate the help.

```
<div class="swatches set1">Swatches</div>
<div class="swatches set2">Swatches</div>
<div class="swatches set3">Swatches</div>
```

```
var swatches = [
"swatch1.png",
"swatch2.png",
"swatch3.png",
"swatch4.png",
"swatch5.png",
"swatch6.png",
"swatch7.png",
"swatch8.png"
];    

var set1 = swatches[3,4,2];
var set2 = swatches[5,1,2];
var set3 = swatches[7,1,2];    

$('.swatches').each(function(){    
    if($(this).hasClass('set1')){
        for(i=0;i<set1.length;i++){
        $(this).append(set1[i]);
        }
    }

    if($(this).hasClass('set2')){
        for(i=0;i<set2.length;i++){
        $(this).append(set2[i]);
        }
    }

    if($(this).hasClass('set3')){
        for(i=0;i<set3.length;i++){
        $(this).append(set3[i]);
        }
    }        
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/NCF92/10/

Comment: Go for `$(this)` instead of `$this`...

Comment: Updated all instances of $this to $(this)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your syntax for sets arrays is invalid.

To make an array using  elements from the `swatches` array it needs to look like:

```
var set1 = [swatches[3],swatches[4],swatches[2]];
```

Answer (score 0):

Two things to take care:

1. `$this` should be `$(this)`, as commented
2. Do like this: `var set1 = [swatches[3],swatches[4],swatches[2]];`

Here is working code:

```
var swatches = [
"swatch1.png",
"swatch2.png",
"swatch3.png",
"swatch4.png",
"swatch5.png",
"swatch6.png",
"swatch7.png",
"swatch8.png"
];


var set1 = [swatches[3],swatches[4],swatches[2]];
var set2 = [swatches[5],swatches[1],swatches[2]];
var set3 = [swatches[7],swatches[1],swatches[2]];
console.log(set1);


$('.swatches').each(function(){

    if($(this).hasClass('set1')){
        for(i=0;i<set1.length;i++){
        $(this).append(set1[i]);
        }
    }

    if($(this).hasClass('set2')){
        for(i=0;i<set2.length;i++){
        $(this).append(set2[i]);
        }
    }

    if($(this).hasClass('set3')){
        for(i=0;i<set3.length;i++){
        $(this).append(set3[i]);
        }
    }

});
```

And **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/NCF92/12/)**.